# Oracle masking data using a trigger

Tags: sql, oracle, triggers

Im trying to create a process that masks data. When I create the trigger I'm getting the error.

ORA-04072: invalid trigger type

I'm unsure why and was hoping someone can explain what the problem is and how to fix it.

The end result is when a user queries cards they should see the masked data and WHEN they query CARDS_TBL they should see all the data (unmasked)

```
Original implementation 

  CREATE TABLE CARDS (
    CARD_ID NUMBER
    GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY,
  CARD_STR VARCHAR2(16) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (CARD_ID)
);

INSERT INTO CARDS(CARD_STR) VALUES('4024007187788590');
INSERT INTO CARDS(CARD_STR) VALUES('5432223398564536');
INSERT INTO CARDS(CARD_STR) VALUES('5430445512530934');
INSERT INTO CARDS(CARD_STR) VALUES('4020156755227854');
INSERT INTO CARDS(CARD_STR) VALUES('5431248766892318');

CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW CARDS_V AS
  SELECT
    CARD_ID,
    REGEXP_REPLACE(CARD_STR, '(^\d{3})(.*)(\d{4}$)', '\1**********\3') AS CARD_STR
  FROM CARDS;

CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER CARDS_TRG_INSERT INSTEAD OF
  INSERT ON CARDS_V
  FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO CARDS (CARD_STR) VALUES (:NEW.CARD_STR);
END;

INSERT INTO CARDS_V (CARD_STR) VALUES ('4011589733550908');

CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER CARDS_TRG_UPDATE INSTEAD OF
  UPDATE ON CARDS_V
  FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  UPDATE CARDS
  SET CARD_STR = :NEW.CARD_STR
  WHERE CARD_ID = :OLD.CARD_ID;
END;



CREATE TABLE CARDS_TBL (
  CARD_ID NUMBER
    GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY,
  CARD_STR VARCHAR2(16) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (CARD_ID)
);

INSERT INTO CARDS_TBL(CARD_STR) VALUES('4024007187788590');
INSERT INTO CARDS_TBL(CARD_STR) VALUES('5432223398564536');
INSERT INTO CARDS_TBL(CARD_STR) VALUES('5430445512530934');
INSERT INTO CARDS_TBL(CARD_STR) VALUES('4020156755227854');
INSERT INTO CARDS_TBL(CARD_STR) VALUES('5431248766892318');


CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW CARDS AS
  SELECT
    CARD_ID,
    REGEXP_REPLACE(CARD_STR, '(^\d{3})(.*)(\d{4}$)', '\1**********\3') AS CARD_STR
  FROM CARDS_TBL;

CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER CARDS_TBL_TRG_UPDATE  BEFORE UPDATE ON CARDS_TBL 
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  UPDATE CARDS_TBL
  SET CARD_STR = :NEW.CARD_STR
  WHERE CARD_ID = :OLD.CARD_ID;
END;
/

CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER CARDS_TBL_TRG_INSERT  BEFORE INSERT ON CARDS 
 FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO CARDS_TBL (CARD_STR) VALUES (:NEW.CARD_STR);
END;


INSERT INTO CARDS_TBL (CARD_STR) VALUES ('2222333344445555');

SELECT * FROM CARDS_TBL;

UPDATE CARDS_TBL 
  SET CARD_STR = '2222333344445566'
  WHERE CARD_ID = 6;
/

SELECT * FROM CARDS;
```

Comment: your syntax is off see https://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/triggers/before_insert.php

Comment: Take a step back, why do you want to use triggers? The view is already doing the regexp_replace  against the tables data. I think you’ve confused two different methods and ended up with something that doesn’t make sense

Comment: @Andrew I was trying to simplify the following implementation. See original post for update

Comment: @Beefstu have you read my comment?

Comment: @nbk yes and I'm passed the original issue. Thanks abs I've updated the original post to reflect that change. Now I'm trying to deal with a muted error on the update

Comment: @Beefstu you have a lot more problmes https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=c9e5eb1308e425a0b609fd3a4e83d5b1

Comment: @nbk I ran this in livesql and didn't get any compilation issues. The point is moot as I'm trying to rewrite the first version and REPLACE it with the second version that has the muted issue. For academic purposes I will try and go back and fix the first version. Its Saturday night and I need to move forward. Thanks for your help and expertise

Comment: "**Muted**" issue? Are you referring to "mutating [table] issue"? Check the meanings of "mute" and "mutate"; there is absolutely no relationship between them.

Comment: Are you trying to write instead of triggers for the views? They don’t really make any sense as they are - before updating the table, update the table

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this particular example, at least, the trigger `CARDS_TBL_TRG_UPDATE` doesn't do anything (except raise a `MUTATING TABLE` exception) and can be dispensed with. Get rid of it and your example runs as expected. [See this db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=e0f230c80b546a4070c5a39942b757bf)